# Change Extension of Library?

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to change a shared library's extension, only on windows from ".dll" to something else?

```
add_library(mylib SHARED <src>)
```

So instead of creating a mylib.dll file i need it to be something else like mylib.dla.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the target's [`SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SUFFIX.html) property, i.e.:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED <src>)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".dla")
```

Answer (score 0):

> `set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".dla")`

will change all suffixes but will work for you as well

Comment: People tend to say that this is bad practice and that one should change the target properties